# visual studio 2019 remove an azure devops connection

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

In visual studio 2019 Team Explorer, I want to completely remove the connection to a azure devops project, but there is not remove button/menu item.
The project is based on git and I don't care what happens to the local repo. I can delete it manually. I just want visual studio to forget it was ever connected to that project.

I can't believe there is not simple way to disconnect from a project!?!?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can right-click the repo you want to remove, and then select the Remove option.
It should be noted that once a repo is added, VS cannot remove the repo by default unless there is another repo, e.g in the figure below, I also have a local repository below. You have to switch to another repository to remove the current one, otherwise the displayed remove option will be unusable.
[image]

Repeating the comment below because it's easier:

> If you go to Team in the menu and select 'Disconnect from Server', then you are allowed to delete a connection without the need of creating a new connection"

Comment: In order for this to work, you need to have at least 2 projects connected. Only then you can delete one them. If you only have one project and you want to delete it, visual studio won't let you. You have to add a connection to dummy project and then you can delete the original one. (Thank you microsoft for giving us the chance to waste our time creating dummy projects!!!!)

Comment: If you go to Team in the menu and select 'Disconnect from Server', then you are allowed to delete a connection without the need of creating a new connection.

Comment: Life saver! I rename one project and I was not able to work with it anymore despite on the manage connection dialog was showing correctly, and is because it can't update a project that you have active even if that project does not exist anymore! An error from team explorer saying so would be nice.

Comment: @BlueIced And where the heck one could find the "Team" menu item? :-) No such thing as far as I could see...

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the plug icon in Team Explorer. You should land on the tab "Connect" where you find a link "Manage Connections".And then choose "Connect to a project" and you will get a dialog with all your connections. With the "Add TFS Server" link above the list of connections you can add and remove TFS server instances. Or you can remove the connection in the displayed connections.
**Team Explorer Connections**

[image: Team Explorer Connections]

Answer (score 2):

**For Visual Studio 2022**

Git menu > Manage Remotes

Opened window > select repository > remove

[image]

[image]